# AM335x - i2c slave for linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, i2c, omap

I need to have i2c slave Linux kernel driver for TI AM335x.
I googled about and didn't find precise information.
Should I do everything from scratch, or maybe someone has some reference about it? or even a patch

Thanks

Avner

Answer (score 0):

For new device which connected as slave to i2c bus, you should write neither "*i2c* driver" nor "driver for *AM335x*" (as far as the processor support [already present](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/mach-omap2) in kernel).

i2c is a bus and there is kernel infrastructure for the bus, see [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/).

You should figure out what type your device is and then write driver for this type of device using i2c bus primitives.

For example, the driver for [DS13xx and compatible IC](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/rtc/rtc-ds1307.c) is *rtc* driver.

A driver "for" PCF8574 i2c gpio expander can be [*GPIO*](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/gpio/gpio-pcf857x.c) driver as well as [*keypad*](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/input/misc/pcf8574_keypad.c) driver.

Comment: I guess you didn't understand my question. If you were familiar with this issue, would know there is **no** such driver for i2c slave in the kernel for AM335x. i2c slave it something not trivial - so what you wrote is not true!

Comment: I'm sorry. Indeed, I used a wrong assumption that _AM335x with linux_ should be an i2c master.

Comment: p.s. I am not "one who voted against" but I compensated the vote. For now the question is interesting fo me.

Comment: Thanks! In 2010 someone wrote such driver (There are posts about it in TI forum) but it has gone. I guess I will have to write it by myself...